# Is it possible to Invoke an button click event using Python WX Wizard?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

New Python(Windows) user here...

I am working with the wx.wizard components and have ran into a bit of a roadblock.

Typically the RunWizard property gets ran and everything is controlled by the event handler.

Rather than having the user manually click the next button, I had a scenario where I wanted to click it for them.

I've spend hours trying to figure this out and here is my best attempt at it so far.

Essentially what I need to do is invoke the wx.EVT_BUTTON event on this button... but I haven't been able to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def on_page_changed(self, evt):
    '''Executed after the page has changed.'''
    if evt.GetDirection():  dir = "forward"
    else:                   dir = "backward"
    page = evt.GetPage()
    print "page_changed: %s, %s\n" % (dir, page.__class__)

    nextbutton = mywiz.FindWindowById(wx.ID_FORWARD)

    button_event = wx.PyCommandEvent(wx.EVT_BUTTON.typeId, self.Id)
    button_event.EventObject = self
    wx.PostEvent(self, button_event)

    if page is self.pages[0]:

        nextbutton = mywiz.FindWindowById(wx.ID_FORWARD)

        button_event = wx.PyCommandEvent(wx.EVT_BUTTON.typeId, self.Id)
        button_event.EventObject = self
        wx.PostEvent(self, button_event)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like under some condition you want to skip a page.  Look at the wxPython demo 'Run Dynamic Wizard' how this can be done.